# Quicklisp error in Lispworks

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, lispworks

I'm running LispWorks 7.1 on OSX (macOS High Sierra). I *sometimes* encounter a Quicklisp loading bug (I say *sometimes* because when I restart LispWorks I *sometimes* don't see this error again).

Example:

```
CL-USER 1 > (ql:quickload "iterate")
To load "iterate":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    asdf
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    iterate

Error: Error detected during deflate decompression: Corrupted Data detected during decompression: Incorrect huffman code (1E55) in huffman decode!
  1 (abort) Give up on "iterate"
  2 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.
```

Any idea what's going on?

I've verified I have a recent client:

```
CL-USER 6 > (ql:update-client)
The most up-to-date client, version 2017-03-06, is already installed.
T
```

Also, the backtrace, in case it helps:

```
CL-USER 12 : 1 > :b
Call to ERROR
Call to QL-GUNZIPPER::DECODE-HUFFMAN-BLOCK
Call to QL-GUNZIPPER::DECODE-BLOCK
Call to QL-GUNZIPPER::INFLATE-STREAM
Call to QL-GUNZIPPER::INFLATE-GZIP-STREAM
Call to QL-GUNZIPPER:GUNZIP
Call to (METHOD QL-DIST:INSTALL (QL-DIST:RELEASE))
Call to (METHOD QL-DIST:ENSURE-INSTALLED (T))
Call to MAP
Call to QUICKLISP-CLIENT::APPLY-LOAD-STRATEGY
Call to QUICKLISP-CLIENT::AUTOLOAD-SYSTEM-AND-DEPENDENCIES
Call to (METHOD QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD (T))
Call to CLOS::NEXT-METHOD-CALL-2
Call to QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS
Call to CLOS::GENERIC-FUNCTION-NON-DISCRIMINATOR
Call to LET
Call to EVAL
Call to CAPI::CAPI-TOP-LEVEL-FUNCTION
Call to CAPI::INTERACTIVE-PANE-TOP-LOOP
Call to MP::PROCESS-SG-FUNCTION
```

Comment: get the latest patches: http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/patch-selection.html

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rainer Joswig pointed out, I just had to (*duh!*) apply the latest patches.

For future reference, this involves

1. Downloading the patches listed [here](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/patch-selection.html)
2. Copying them to the appropriate `private-patches` directory (e.g. `/Applications/LispWorks\ 7.1\ \(64-bit\)/Library/lib/7-1-0-0/private-patches` for me)
3. Modifying `load.lisp` in the directory accordingly (in this case, adding `(load-one-private-patch "lisp-memory-copy-32-chunks" :system64)` and 
   `(load-one-private-patch "replace-i-vectors" :system)`)
4. Restarting Lispworks